# getVisitorData() returns NULL on Category Page only in magento-1.9.2.2

Tags: magento-1.9, category, theme, currency, url-key

On my Porto theme with Magento 1.9.2.2, Currency Switcher is not working on category_list page and product_view page. On both of these pages, switching the currency always returns Base Currency. 
Using the URL like this

> http://example.com/catalog/category/view/id/82  (working well)

works fine i.e., the currency changed. Also getting the visitor's information using following method returns the array with information.

> Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getVisitorData();

But with the URL with URL key doesn't work. and getVisitorData() returns NULL value on the links with URL-key like following.

> http://example.com/category.html   (doesn't work)

Please help me to figure this out.
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

hello @Muhammad Salid,

Why you don't use a extension for it ?

For example: http://goo.gl/LUpfa3

Comment: thanks @michel but the extension is paid. Also I just want to run the default functionality first.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the visitor data is set in the session in

`Mage_Log_Model_Visitor::saveByRequest`

```
public function saveByRequest($observer)
{
    if ($this->_skipRequestLogging || $this->isModuleIgnored($observer)) {
        return $this;
    }

    try {
        $this->setLastVisitAt(now());
        $this->save();
        $this->_getSession()->setVisitorData($this->getData());
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        Mage::logException($e);
    }
    return $this;
}
```

You've got three things to debug.

1. Is your module ignored? Pop logging in the `isModuleIgnored` function.
2. Is the `_skipRequestLogging` set to true? It seems to be based on config and depending on the user agent. See `Mage_Log_Model_Visitor::_construct`.
3. Is there some sort of exception happening, check your exception log.

It's going to be one of these failing. My bet would be on points 1 or 2 but that's pure conjecture.

Comment: Thanks @Luke 1) isModuleIgnored returns False and 2) _skipRequestLogging set to False. Also No exception in exception.log